# jQuery jqGrid - select box within grid row

Tags: jquery, html, xml, select, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid 4.5.2 & am using a custom formatter to build a dropdown box in a cell in a jqGrid row based on values from other (hidden) cells.

The dropdown box's selections get built from the results of a query to a SQL table.  In addition, I also prepend a row to it as an instructional message.  The dropdown gets built as follows:

```
function getMsgs() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: myUrl,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
                var select = $("#msglist");
                var selectline = $("<option value='0'>Select Message</option>");
                    select.prepend(selectline);
                    $(data).find("Row").each(function() {
                var ctid = $(this).find("CannedTextID").text();
                var dtext = $(this).find("DisplayText").text();
                var option = $("<option>" + dtext + "</option>");
                option.prop("value", ctid);
                   select.append(option);
                });
        // make the instructional message unselectable
        $("#msglist option[value='0']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });

    msgSelect = $("#msglist").select();
}
```

The results are put into a form in the page & the HTML is as follows:

```
<form class="Messages" action="">
<select id="msglist" class="choices" name="msglist">
<option value="0" disabled="disabled">Select Message</option>
<option value="7"> Message2</option>
<option value="8"> Message3</option>
<option value="9"> Message4</option>
<option value="10"> Message5</option>
<option value="11"> Message6</option>
<option value="12"> Message7</option>
<option value="13">Intermittent problems</option>
<option value="14">Local Network Connectivity issue</option>
<option value="15">Message15</option>
</select>
</form>
```

At the end of the function, I set a global variable `msgSelect = $("#msglist").select();`

Within the formatter, on the conditions that meet where the dropdown is supposed to be, I return:

`return msgSelect[0].outerHTML;`

This displays the dropdown box in the jqGrid, but instead of showing the first row = `Select Message` as the initial dropdown box does, it shows `Message2` instead.  In the jqGrid row, the `Select Message` is greyed out & cannot be selected, but the dropdown defaults to the second row.  The `select` is identical to the HTML in the dropdown box that I put elsewhere on the page (i.e. `Select Message` is disabled, and is not set as default in either place).

Why is the jqGrid custom formatter displaying the HTML differently, even though the code is exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  The issue was in using `IE` vs `Firefox`.  IE was selecting it by default, whereas I had to set the attribute `selected` if I wanted to have Firefox do the same thing.

I had not noticed that the original dropdown box had the `Select Message` in black (Firefox) in the list and grey within the dropdown, while IE had both of them greyed out.